# Organic and Referral Traffic mismatch on Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am here once again. I have noticed that one of my client's website  Organic traffic and referral traffic data have mismatched on Google analytics. When I calculate daily organic data of last 7 day's data then total traffic is 1,933 but the Google analytics is showing 1,805 same as on referral traffic total data of last 7 days is 355 but the google analytics is showing 276. I do not understand why is the data showing mismatched? Please help me. Here is the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: In what way are they mismatched? Mismatched compared to what? You're calculating from where? If it's from server log files, the disparity is probably due to filters used by Analytics (typically bots being excluded) or perhaps users with JavaScript disabled.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I basically calculate the data on daily basic and maintain an excel. For an example on daily basis traffic below:

1st Jan -  Organic traffic received : 295
2nd Jan - Organic traffic received : 223
3rd Jan - Organic traffic received : 273
4th Jan -Organic traffic received : 269
5th Jan - Organic traffic received : 287
6th - Organic traffic received : 313
7th Jan - Organic traffic received : 273

So If I calculate the total number of data of last 7 days then total traffic should be 1,933 but analytics is showing 1,805. I do not have any filter.

Comment: I do not create any filter on analytics. and that's my concern if daily data got right on analytics then why did total traffic got mismatched by Google analytics. It will be applied for referral traffic data as well.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing a daily running tally of users on the site, with the weekly total in Analytics.

The problem is, if a visitor comes to the site more than once during that week, you'll be counting them each time in the daily tally, and Analytics will only count them once for the week. As "Users" is literally "individual visitors during this period" (although that's based on Analytics best estimation, using devices and accounts, so it's not entirely foolproof).

As an example, let's say there are three people who have visited your site, Person A, Person B, and Person C.

- Person A visits the site on Monday and Tuesday.
- Person B visits the site only on Monday.
- Person C visits the site only on Tuesday.

Looking at the Analytics data for **just** Monday or Tuesday, would both show two users, because two *different* users visited the site each day. But looking at the data for **both** Monday and Tuesday would show only three users, because only three different users visited the site over that period.

That is what accounts for the discrepancy you're seeing.

A better metric might be to look at sessions. Those are each unique and represent the sum of all visits to the site.

If you'd like to see a breakdown of daily users that does match with the weekly total, you can add "Day of the Month" as a secondary dimension to the weekly report. That will show you the totals with users returning during that period excluded from subsequent days. There are several "day" secondary dimensions, but in your case "day of the month" is going to give the clearest breakdown of data.

Comment: Here is the breakdown of organic traffic for last 7 days: (News users 1,544 + returning 396 = 1,940). Thank you for clarification.